# want to change color of multiple divs for few seconds but only which are loaded recently

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i am loading divs dynamically on request with the help of ajax,now what i want is to highlight them for few seconds but with `$('div.eachrow').effect("highlight",{color:'#FCE8E8'},3000)` this code it highlights all divs with the class `eachrow`,so is there any way highlight only recently loaded divs ??

```
success: function(html) {
        if (html) {
            ++itr;
            $('#quepanel').append(html);
            $('div.eachrow').effect("highlight",{color:'#FCE8E8'},3000);
            $('div#loadMore').hide();
        }
```

Comment: Try jquery .css () for the highlight.

Comment: You could add a .fresh class to them, and setTimeout(something) to remove that class later.

Comment: @mike : can pls give me the perfect code to work it fine ..???

Answer (score 2):

You can create a jQuery object and then highlight it:

```
success: function(html) {
        if (html) {
            ++itr;
            var $html = $(html);
            $html.appendTo('#quepanel');
            $html.effect("highlight",{color:'#FCE8E8'},3000);
            $('div#loadMore').hide();
        }
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundImage' of undefined

Comment: @007Ketul Do you use this code? Which line throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutation events to identify which elements where inserted: Open console and see logs. The event fires when something is inserted in "test" div.

Html:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="add" onclick="$('<div>dyn</div>').appendTo('#test')" />​
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  // ...
    console.log(ev.target);
}, false);​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LA3LZ/

Answer (score 0):

In the success handler, wrap HTML with jQuery first. This will create DOM elements right away.

Then you can work on the Ajax-loaded elements only.

```
success: function(html) {
    if (html) {
        ++itr;
        html = $(html); // Do this.

        $('$quepanel').append(html);

        html.effect('hightlight', { color: '#FCE8E8' }, 3000);

        $('div#loadMore').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundImage' of undefined

Comment: You may want to be careful when working with hightlight() and the css background at the same time, see if this link helps out http://house9.blogspot.hk/2009/03/jqueryui-effect-error-with-google.html.